# how do i set the correct height when using javascript google bar chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, bar-chart

i am using [google bar chart](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/barchart.html#Loading) and in the options there is a height property.  depending on my dataset i need to set a different height as things either get squeezed together or there is tons of whitespace above and below the bar chart.

is there anyway to have the chart know how much height it needs based on the number of items in the datatable?

Comment: Can you include an example of both extremes? I believe I have a workaround but need to make sure it is applicable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you run into issues dynamically resizing based on dataset size?

e.g., on the [Code Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#bar_chart):

```
line 31            width:600, height: data.getNumberOfRows() * 80,
```

Answer (score 2):

no, at least not using the bar chart API but it wouldn't be too hard for you to make a method :D